# Spring third party authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

What I want is first check local database for authentication. if user is not authenticated. make a rest call with username and password to another server which returns a success message and complete user bean. which I want to store in spring security session. how can I achive this.? I tried with loadUserByUsername() method but there is no password parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Start with this and then expand your research from there:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-auth-manager

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement your own version of [AuthenticationProvider](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html) interface.

Inject it in your security configuration with something like:

```xml
<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider ref="myAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>
```